# Reformatting JSON Files in R

Tags: r, json, api

I have a JSON file formatted as follows:

```
[
  {
    "StreetAddress": "",
    "City": "",
    "State": "",
    "Zip": "V6A 2P3",
    "County": "",
    "Country": "",
    "SPLC": "",
    "CountryPostalFilter": "",
    "AbbreviationFormat": "",
    "CountryAbbreviation": ""
  },
  {
    "StreetAddress": "",
    "City": "",
    "State": "",
    "Zip": "V6A 2P3",
    "County": "",
    "Country": "",
    "SPLC": "",
    "CountryPostalFilter": "",
    "AbbreviationFormat": "",
    "CountryAbbreviation": ""
  }
]
```

Is there R script I can use to reformat the file as follows:

```
{
  "Locations": [
    {
      "Address": {
        "StreetAddress": "1000 Herrontown Rd",
        "City": "Princeton",
        "State": "NJ",
        "Zip": "",
        "County": "",
        "Country": null,
        "SPLC": "",
        "CountryPostalFilter": 0,
        "AbbreviationFormat": 0,
        "CountryAbbreviation": "US"
      }
    },
    {
      "Address": {
        "StreetAddress": "457 N Harrison St",
        "City": "",
        "State": "",
        "Zip": "08540",
        "County": "",
        "Country": null,
        "SPLC": "",
        "CountryPostalFilter": 0,
        "AbbreviationFormat": 0
      }
     }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df <- jsonlite::fromJSON('[
  {
    "StreetAddress": "",
    "City": "",
    "State": "",
    "Zip": "V6A 2P3",
    "County": "",
    "Country": "",
    "SPLC": "",
    "CountryPostalFilter": "",
    "AbbreviationFormat": "",
    "CountryAbbreviation": ""
  },
  {
    "StreetAddress": "",
    "City": "",
    "State": "",
    "Zip": "V6A 2P3",
    "County": "",
    "Country": "",
    "SPLC": "",
    "CountryPostalFilter": "",
    "AbbreviationFormat": "",
    "CountryAbbreviation": ""
  }
]')
```

In comparison with @Brian's answer, I don't set `simplifyDataFrame = F` so the JSON form will be converted to a `data.frame` object in R. Then use `tibble()` to put this data frame into a 2x1 data frame with column name `Address`(This is a little tricky because base `data.frame()` cannot do that).

```
res <- list(Locations = tibble::tibble(Address = df))
jsonlite::toJSON(res, pretty = T)
```

**Edit:** This method works even when I set `simplifyDataFrame = F`, because `tibble()` also allow named lists as columns.

---

**Output**

```
{
  "Locations": [
    {
      "Address": {
        "StreetAddress": "",
        "City": "",
        "State": "",
        "Zip": "V6A 2P3",
        "County": "",
        "Country": "",
        "SPLC": "",
        "CountryPostalFilter": "",
        "AbbreviationFormat": "",
        "CountryAbbreviation": ""
      }
    },
    {
      "Address": {
        "StreetAddress": "",
        "City": "",
        "State": "",
        "Zip": "V6A 2P3",
        "County": "",
        "Country": "",
        "SPLC": "",
        "CountryPostalFilter": "",
        "AbbreviationFormat": "",
        "CountryAbbreviation": ""
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This approach is a little cleaner, great job.

Comment: Your approach works even with `simplifyDataFrame = F`, because you can have named lists as columns in tibbles as well.

Comment: @Brian good point! I didn't notice that. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: I think I am getting very close here.  However, my output is now as follows:

Comment: @dkent Do you use the same data and code above? Or you change something?

Comment: Yes, I changed something.  I am using a JSON file created from a data frame.  Before putting that file through your script, however, I get exactly my starting format from my initial comment above.

Comment: @dkent Does the JSON file look like the form in your question? How did you read that file? Input its url to `fromJSON()` or just copy/paste the context?

Comment: My script is:  Step A:
Test1 <- toJSON(input, dataframe = c("rows", "columns", "values"),pretty = TRUE)
write(Test1, "test.json")

Step B:
res <- list(Locations = tibble::tibble(Address = Test1))
res2 <- jsonlite::toJSON(res, pretty = T)
write(res2, "res.json")


After Step A, I get the result I first mention in my initial post.  After step B, I get the further odd looking result above.

Comment: @dkent I think you got it wrong. If `input` is a data frame object, revise step B to `res <- list(Locations = tibble::tibble(Address = input))`. And run the rest of the code. Check whether the file `res.json` is what you want.

Comment: That did it - perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

```
df<-jsonlite::fromJSON('[
  {
    "StreetAddress": "",
    "City": "",
    "State": "",
    "Zip": "V6A 2P3",
    "County": "",
    "Country": "",
    "SPLC": "",
    "CountryPostalFilter": "",
    "AbbreviationFormat": "",
    "CountryAbbreviation": ""
  },
  {
    "StreetAddress": "",
    "City": "",
    "State": "",
    "Zip": "V6A 2P3",
    "County": "",
    "Country": "",
    "SPLC": "",
    "CountryPostalFilter": "",
    "AbbreviationFormat": "",
    "CountryAbbreviation": ""
  }
]', simplifyDataFrame = F)

purrr::map(df, ~list(Address = .x)) %>% 
  list(Locations = .) %>% 
  jsonlite::toJSON(pretty = T, auto_unbox = T)
```

I think this reproduces your desired output exactly.